# Ajax Javascript code not working properly after building it as an APK

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
function giveFeedBack() {
    var category = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
    var rating = document.getElementById("sel2").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    var Device_ID = "123456789";
    var userid = "1";
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://tacoi.in/api/feedback.php",
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: { feed_id: category, rating: rating, description: message, Device_ID: Device_ID, userid: userid },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("FeedBack Submitted Successfully");
            var url2 = 'books.html';
            location.href = url2;        
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
            //var url = 'books.html';
            ///location.href = url;
        }
    });
    
}
```

```html
         <button type="button" id="btnFeed" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="margin-top: 14px;border-radius: 0;">
                SUBMIT
            </button>



   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnFeed').click(function () {
                debugger;
                //getUserData();
                giveFeedBack();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my Javascript code which runs properly on localhost; but when I make an APK and run on my phone it doesn't run and gives popup as "Not Found" after I click Submit button.

Comment: have you tried making the url https?? `https://tacoi.in/api/feedback.php`

Comment: yes.I've already gone through it. but the url provided to me is as above only